# JetBrains IDE - Keyboard shortcut to jump to closing HTML tag

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm, jetbrains-ide

In JetBrains IDEs (such as WebStorm) is there a keyboard shortcut to jump to the matching end HTML tag or matching beginning HTML tag?

Answer (score 15):

Yes there is:

- <kbd>Ctrl - [</kbd> to jump to the beginning tag
- <kbd>Ctrl - ]</kbd> to jump to the ending tag

In `Settings -> Appearance & Behavior -> Keymap`, these are the "Move Caret to Code Block End" and "Move Caret to Code Block Start" actions.

Comment: You can also assign shortcut to `Editor Actions | Move Caret to Matching Brace` action -- it navigates between opening and closing brace/tag with one shortcut.

Comment: Some time ago I have been looking for the same shortcut in Eclipse.